# React-native-sound import crashes the App

Tags: react-native, react-native-sound

I'm not new to React, but I'm new to React Native. I've jumped very optimistic to it, but for now it looks like one big fat buggy thing. I wanted to build just simple metronome, but spent hours dealing with bugs. And here's one more. `react-native-sound` package just doesn't want to work. I follow documentation and just right after `var Sound = require('react-native-sound');` app crashes with

```
./node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image/AssetSourceResolver.js:25:17
Module not found: Can't resolve '../Utilities/Platform'
  23 | const PixelRatio = require('../Utilities/PixelRatio');
  24 | const {pickScale} = require('./AssetUtils');
> 25 | const Platform = require('../Utilities/Platform');
     |                 ^
  26 |
  27 | const invariant = require('invariant');
  28 |
```

I just can't find the answer why it happens. Any ideas? My app was created with Expo.

P.S.: Everything I've worked with in web developement, even if we're speaking about some small not very popular packages seems like heaven with super clear documentation, q&a's around the internet etc. compare to React native stuff. So if idea of using RN was the bad idea, just let me know)

Comment: Have you found any solution ? @meAndrew?

Comment: @MuhammadHassaan nah... It's not the right time for me to work with RN)

Comment: It was just linking issue. adding this comment in case someone else facing the same issue.